# How to import a csv file resides on hdfs to mysql database using python scripts

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I have a use cases where after aggregation(using map-reduce), a csv file is generated. Now, i want to import this csv file which is resides on hdfs to directly to mysql database.
I have written this code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
import csv
import MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='test')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

def main():
    #csv_data = csv.reader(file(path/to/local/testcsv.csv))
    csv_data = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", 'path/to/hdfs/testcsv.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #for row in csv_data
    for row in csv_data.stdout:
        print row
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
          classes, mark )' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
          row)
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#close the connection to the database.
print "Done"
```

testcsv.csv contains three field names, classes and marks. I have created testcsv table in mysql and trying to import using oozie workflow. My oozie workflow runs fine when importing csv from local file system instead of hdfs(shown in commented lines).
running this code doesn't import data to mysql. **Am i doing some mistake?**

Comment: Have you considered using [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org) for dumping data from HDFS to MySQL ?

Comment: yes, but i cant use sqoop since my use case is different. Each time, i have to read a csv line by line from file resides on hdfs and import the line in 3 different table with some other values.